# Bash set Variable Function

Tags: bash

I have a function that gets an app name and version

```
function get_versions() {
ver_file="versions.txt";
for service in $(cat $ver_file | cut -f1 -d:) ; do
 for ver in $(grep $service $ver_file | cut -f2 -d:) ; do 
  local $service_ ver=$ver;
 done;
done;
}
```

I want to set environment variables like apache-ver=2.0 for example.
(by echo will be echo $apache-ver)
the versions.txt look like that:
apache:2.0

I tried a lot of ways to set it
but i didn't found a solution for that
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my version.  I dispense with the `cat` and the `cut`, using `IFS` and `read` instead.  Notice that any variable that is encapsulated within the function is marked as `local`.

You can't have a variable name containing a hyphen in bash, so `apache-ver=2.0` is invalid.   I have used an underscore instead.

The variables are dynamically created using `eval`, and this is one of the few occasions where it is useful, but why you want to dynamically create a variable name is a mystery.  You could easily add `export` to that line if required, however since the dynamic variable is not marked as local then it is visible throughout the script.

```
# Use fuction, or (), not both
get_versions() {
    local ver_file="versions.txt"
    local service ver

    while IFS=':' read service ver
    do
        local name="${service}_ver"

        # Sanitize edit
        name=${name/[\-.]/'_'}
        eval "$name='$ver'"
    done < "$ver_file"
}  

get_versions
echo $apache_ver
echo $tester_ver
```

My `versions.txt` looks like this:

```
apache:2.0
tester:3.3
```

The script outputs:

```
2.0
3.3
```

Comment: Hi.thanks, what do you mean "Use function, or (), not both"? examples pls?

Comment: i have problem, lines like "apr-util:1.5.4" , "php5.4:5.4.45" , give me error of "1.sh: line 6: apr-util_ver=1.5.4: command not found" , "1.sh: line 6: php5.4_ver=5.4.45: command not found"

Comment: Use `export` instead of `eval`. Aside from security concerns, `eval` would require `$ver` to be properly quoted. Compare `eval "foo=1 2"` with `export "foo=1 2"`.

Comment: i didn't understand. can you provide me how to do?

Comment: As I said in my post, a hyphen (minus sign) is not a valid character to have in a variable name, neither is a `.`.  You are only allowed alphanumerics or an underscore, and the first character must be an alpha (in common with most languages).  You will have to sanitise the name, or more likely reconsider the need for a dynamic variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use export to archive this

```
/ # cat versions.txt
aaaa:01
bbbb:02

/ # cat test.sh
#/bin/bash

ver_file=versions.txt
for service in $(cat $ver_file | cut -f1 -d:) ; do
 for ver in $(grep $service $ver_file | cut -f2 -d:) ; do 
  echo export $service=$ver
 done;
done;

/ # eval $(./test.sh)
/ # echo $aaaa
01
/ # echo $bbbb
02
/ #
```